# Using Wicked with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

It's been a nightmare trying to integrate the two.

Update:

**UsersController.rb**

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :confirm_password

  def show
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    render_wizard
  end

end
```

**RegistrationsController (devise)**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def new
  super
 end

 def create
  super
 end

 protected
    def users_steps_path(resource)
        '/user_steps'
    end
end
```

**confirm_password.html.erb (view)**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
  <%=  f.password_field :password_confirmation  %>

  <%= f.submit "Change Password" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :user_steps
```

**registrations/new.html.erb (sign up)**

```
<div class="styled email-input2">

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "email-input"  %></div>

<div><%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Username", class: "email-input"  %></div>

<div><%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "email-input"  %></div>

<div><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password confirmation", class: "email-input"  %></div>


</div>
  <div class="get_motivated2">
     <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "get_motivated btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>


</div>
```

This is what I have so far, but when I sign-up with devise it just logs me in.. It doesn't go to the :confirm_password step. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I've followed Ryan Bates tutorial on railscasts, but he doesn't use Devise which threw me off a bit.

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to do? And what is your problem?

Comment: I don't know where to put the redirect_to user_steps_path(:billing) step in the registrations controller.. it's extremely complicated. Please help

Comment: I suggest that you describe the wizard that you're trying to implement with wicked. Show the code of the step that you're having problems with. More information means you have more chances to get people here troubleshoot your problem. This is an example question with detailed information http://bit.ly/1qLjARf

Comment: Thanks @Hoa, updated the post. Hopefully this will help you solve it! I've been trying for hours

Comment: What are the steps of the wizard? After a user fills out the signup form (this form doesn't contain password fields), he's redirected to a page where he provides password and password confirmation?

Comment: correct, that's how I would like it to work

Comment: If so, what do the view (the signup form) look like?

Comment: Updated the post with the sign up form

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to do is: after a user fills out the sign up form (a user record is not yet created in this step), the user is redirected to a page where she confirms her password one more time before her user account is created.

When you submit your signup form to `registration_path(resource_name)`, devise will create a new user record and log you in. The place where you should submit all user information to create an user account is in `confirm_password.html.erb`. Submitting the sign up form should simply store the data (this is done by `wicked`) and redirect the user to the password confirmation page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Hoa, this does help! Care to provide an example of how this code would look for my case?